# How to access cookie in onEnter function, react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, koa

Im creating a react component. OnEnter function, i need to access the cookie to get the user-id. But in OnEnter function, cookie is undefined. Im using node-Koa, koa-cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Koa Cookies are by default set to HTTP-only, which means it's not accessible with document.cookies on the client-side for security purposes.

When you set the cookie, set the httpOnly option to false, and it should work.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://koajs.com/#context), and scroll to the `ctx.cookies.set(name, value, [options])` part. You can see the available options when setting a cookie -- you need to explicitly set httpOnly to false.

Comment: Im calling this function in OnEnter from the component.
router.get('/auth', async (ctx) => {
console.log(ctx.cookie) // this returns undefined
});

I pass httpOnly as false.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand -- but are you running the Koa `router.get()` function in your React component? I'm not familiar with Koa -- but it's a Node.js framework, which means you can't call it on the client side. You need to use an HTTP client for the browser, like [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). Use `axios.get("/auth")` in your React component, `router.get("/auth",...) in your server, and it should work.

Comment: I'm using koa-cookie npm package to access the cookie from ctx.

My code is like: 
import cookie from 'koa-cookie';
router.use(cookie());
router.get('/auth', async (ctx) => { console.log(ctx.cookie) };

Comment: You can't access the cookie like that if you're doing it on the client-side. If you set httpOnly to false the correct way to access that cookie is with document.cookie. Koa-cookie is a server-side module.

Comment: im using react server side rendering. So i need to access cookie in server side. I can access cookie after ComponentDidMount. But here, i need to get it inside onEnter.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code on the server-side.

Comment: import cookie from 'koa-cookie';
import router from 'koa-router';

router.use(cookie());

router.get('/auth', async (ctx) => {
  const ctx2 = ctx;
  ctx2.body = await checkCookie(ctx);
});

const checkCookie = (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.cookie)
};

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should get cookies without any library.
Use below code.

```
const getCookies = function () {
  var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
  var cookiesObj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
      cookiesObj[(pair[0] + '').trim()] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return cookiesObj;
};
const cookies = getCookies();
```